# how to write multiple rule in cakephp 2x

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My question is when user post new article i want to do no required the text field, but when user edit the post i want required the text field.
**what is wrong in my code please**

```
public $validate = [
    'title' => [
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'rule' => ['maxLength','20'],
        'on' => 'create',
        'message' => 'over 20 words'
    ],
    'status' => [
        [
            'rule' => ['maxLength','200'],
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => 'over 200 words',
            'last' => true,
        ],
        [
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'rule' => ['maxLength','200'],
            'on' => 'update',
            'message' => 'over 200 words',
            'last' => true, 
        ],
    ],  
];
```

Comment: What field do you talk about, `title` or `status` ?

Comment: thx i already solve